# Как с помощью js перебирать объекты на странице, и менять для них стиль

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Допустим у меня на странице 10 или 50 или 800 объектов(одинаковых), не принципиально, и вот мне нужно с помощью js перебрать их всех и каждому из них задать рандомный background, рандомный цвет получать я могу, но мне нужно перебрать все объекты на странице и задать каждому свой цвет.

Подскажите пожалуйста)

Comment: Не понятно. Вообще весь ДОМ перебрать, или определённые объекты? Ну типа с таким-то айдишником, или с таким-то классом, или с по таком-то тэгу?

Comment: 800 объектов <hr id="hr">

Comment: Так не бывает. Это семантически неправильно. Айдишник должен быть уникальным на странице.

Answer (score 1):

Но можно так

```js
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
let elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.d')];

elements.forEach(elem => {
  elem.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
});
```

```css
.d {
display: block;
width: 50px;
height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d">DIV</div>
<div class="d">DIV</div>
<div class="d">DIV</div>
<div class="d">DIV</div>
<div class="d">DIV</div>
<div class="d">DIV</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Или можно так.

```js
let elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.d')];

const getRandomInt = (max) => Math.round(Math.random() * max);

elements.forEach(elem => {
  elem.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${getRandomInt(255)},${getRandomInt(255)},${getRandomInt(255)})`;
});
```

```css
.d {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d">DIV</div>
<div class="d">DIV</div>
<div class="d">DIV</div>
<div class="d">DIV</div>
<div class="d">DIV</div>
<div class="d">DIV</div>
```

Comment: colors забыли убрать, четвертое число не нужно для rgb)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME да, первоначально еще хотел альфа канал добавить, но потом лень стало :)